# Access violation when executing ShellCode via CreateThread

Tags: c, memory, access-violation, shellcode

I Created an executable that contains a Shell code.
The ShellCode is suppose to execute calc.exe.
I use CreateThread to execute the ShellCode.
The Shellcode is indeed executed and calc.exe spawns.
BUT!!! few milliseconds after, my executable crashes.
When Running the code is VS, I get an error of 0xC0000005 (Access Violation).
This happens when I run different ShellCodes as well.

I tried 2 techniques, of holding the ShellCode (stack and heap)

```
int main()
{
int payload_len = 4;

unsigned char* payload = (unsigned char*)malloc(payload_len * sizeof(unsigned char));
if (payload == NULL)
{
    printf("Malloc Error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

unsigned char payload_2[] =
"\0x90\0x90\0xcc\xc3";

RtlMoveMemory(payload, payload_2, payload_len);

//Allocate a memory buffer that will recive the shellcode from the FileMapping later
void* page_to_execute;
page_to_execute = (unsigned char*)VirtualAlloc(0, payload_len, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

//Copy the payload from the FileMappingObject to the newly allocated memory page
RtlMoveMemory(page_to_execute, payload, payload_len);

//Converte the new memory page from RW -> RWX
DWORD OldProtect = 0;
int result = VirtualProtect(page_to_execute, payload_len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldProtect);

DWORD TID;
HANDLE th =::CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)page_to_execute, 0, 0, &TID);
WaitForSingleObject(th, -1);
```

}

```
int main()
{
    int payload_len = 4;

    unsigned char payload[] =
    "\0x90\0x90\0xcc\xc3";

    //Allocate a memory buffer that will recive the shellcode from the FileMapping later
    void* page_to_execute;
    page_to_execute = (unsigned char*)VirtualAlloc(0, payload_len, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    //Copy the payload from the FileMappingObject to the newly allocated memory page
    RtlMoveMemory(page_to_execute, payload, payload_len);

    //Converte the new memory page from RW -> RWX
    DWORD OldProtect = 0;
    int result = VirtualProtect(page_to_execute, payload_len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldProtect);

    DWORD TID;
    HANDLE th =::CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)page_to_execute, 0, 0, &TID);
    WaitForSingleObject(th, -1);
}
```

---

As indicated before, the Shellcode itself doesn't matter as it even happens with the following one: \0x90\0x90\0xcc\xc3
Thus I kept the long (clac.exe) Shellcode outside (same outcome process crashes)

Both Create the same issue.
When looking at the Memory Address of the error using ProcessHacker its exactly the end of the ShellCode.

Any one has any idea why this happening?

64bit machine  -  Windows 10

Comment: Do you expect potential answerers to de-hex and disassemble the payload themselves? If you want an answer, make it easier for the community, please.

Comment: Hey Seva.
It doesn't matter what ShellCode I use, it happens.
Another much shorter example is   0x90, 0x90, 0xcc, 0xc3 Which really doesn't need any exlanation....

Comment: My working theory was that the shellcode didn't terminate correctly. To confirm that, one would need to see the shellcode.